# Проблема с TitaniumWeb Proxy

Tags: c#, сервер, веб-сервер, proxy, redirect

Всем привет, всё-таки получилось у меня реализовать свой проект, который должен был ловить трафик и, при открытии сайтов, которые я занёс в ЧС, открывать сайты аналоги(на моём компе идеально работает). Но такова проблема: Скомпилил я EXEшник, склеил с либами, перекинул на другой комп и начал тестить там. В итоге, ничего не работает, браузер просто сбрасывает соединение, также вылазит такое окно [image: введите сюда описание изображения] тут нажимаю "да", потом меня спрашивает разрешение брендмауэр, там тоже даю доступ, но всё равно соединение сбрасывается.

```
        public static ProxyServer proxyServer  = new ProxyServer();
    public static void Start()
    {

            var endpoint = new ExplicitProxyEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 4848, true);
            proxyServer.AddEndPoint(endpoint);
            proxyServer.Start();

            proxyServer.BeforeRequest += OnRequest;
    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        proxyServer.BeforeRequest -= OnRequest;
        proxyServer.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("СТОПАНУЛ СЕРВАК!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    }

    private static async Task OnRequest(object sender, SessionEventArgs e)
    {
            if (e.HttpClient.Request.RequestUri.Host.Contains("vk.com"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Редиректаем на ЮТТТТТТТТТТТТТТТТТТТТТТТТТТТТТ");
                e.Redirect("https://youtube.com");
                Console.WriteLine("РЕДИРЕКТНУЛИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИ");
            }
    }
```

Также, когда я перенёс этот код в проект WinForms, вынес работу сервера в отдельный поток, то браузер не даёт открывать сайты, выдаёт ошибку о том, что мошенники пытаются украсть данные, хотя, я делаю (тестово) редирект с vk.com на youtube.com. Помогите, пожалуйста, буду очень признателен любой помощи

Comment: Почитайте про MITM атаки, это поможет понять в чем дело.

Comment: так, проблему с тем, что обрывалось соединение я решил(была несовместимость библиотек). Теперь надо решить проблему с тем, что браузер выдаёт ошибку, что мошенники хотят похитить данные. @aepot, то, про что вы написали (MITM атаки), поможет мне попробовать разобраться?

Comment: Это даст ответ, на что ругается браузер

Comment: @aepot, да, это дало ответ, это из-за сертификации, но, как можно это исправить, использую TitaniumWeb Proxy? Я погуглил, но внятного ответа не получил, сможете как-то помочь, пожалуйста?

Comment: Не могу, я никогда не реализовывал MITM-Proxy

Comment: @aepot А что делать, если прога, как бы, работает на моём пк и на ноуте, т.е. выполняет редирект, но скинул я товарищу, он запустил, она у него работает, нет никаких ошибок, но редирект не выполняет. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: "У меня справа рука, сильно болит, а слева точно такая же рука и не болит. С чем это может быть связано?" Перестаньте верить в магию, научитесь отлаживать, снифать трафик, сравнивать другие параметры окружения. Ответы дает отладка, а не гипотеза. Гипотеза подсказывает, что отлаживать. Я подсказал.